# The limit of characterstic of normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $ϕ_n$ is the characterstic function of $N(0,n)$ random variable $n=1,2, \cdots$, prove that $ϕ_n(t)\to ϕ(t)$ as $n \to \infty $ but that $ϕ$ is not continous at the origin.

I konw the characterstic function of normal is $\exp(imt- σ^2 x^2/2)$, then the characteristic function of $N(0,n)$ is $\exp(-n^2 x^2/2)$.

$ϕ_n(t) = \exp(-n^2 x^2/2)$ then $ϕ_n(t) \to ϕ(t)=0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic function for the normal distribution $N(0,n)$ (assuming $n$ is the standard deviation) should be
$$
\phi_n(t) = \exp\big( -\frac{1}{2}n^2t^2 \big)
$$
The convergence is pointwise, so actually the limit is
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(t) = \phi(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & t=0\\
0 & t\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
since $\phi_n(0) = 1$ for all $n$.  The limit $\phi$ is not continuous at $0$.